# VK_OEM_4 keeps accessing the start menu button?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual-keyboard

Im making a program in which c++ presses keys on the keyboard automatically for me. I have done this with every key on the keyboard. It works perfectly EXCEPT for when i am trying to use square brackets '['. If i tell the computer to print out a square bracket, it prints out the square bracket as expected, but it also presses the windows start button, therefore opening the start menu? So my question is WHY is this happening? is VK_OEM_4 somehow linked to the start button? (huh?) PS Before anyone asks, my code is 100% correct for every key so i know the methods i am using works.

Comment: 126 views, yet no ideas :(